# How to redirect from host name to domain name using url rewrite

Tags: .net, iis, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site which is accessible both by these urls inside my domain:

```
http://test 
http://test.mydomain.com
```

I'm trying to set up a redirect from `http://test` to `http://test.mydomain.com` using url rewriting, this is the rule I have at the moment:

```
<rule name="domain redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^test(.*)$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://test.mydomain.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

But it creates redirect loop. I know there is something small I'm missing, can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file (if it's not already created) called ".htaccess" without quotes and put in the following code (changing "test" and "mydomain", of course):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://test.mydomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Isn't `.htaccess` Apache file? Besides there is no .con in first case, it's a server alias inside domain.

Comment: @Burjua Can't believe I didn't realze that! Should I just take the answer off then?

Comment: As you wish, although it might help somebody.